How do I make a script that uses PAGER comply with the most popular shells?
I have a script that basically looks like this:
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  bold="$(tput bold)"
  unbold="$(tput sgr0)"
else
  bold=""
  unbold=""
fi
TEXT="
${bold}Hello World${unbold}
There's a bunch of text in here that I don't control, but I
can escape it, so I put slashes before double quotes (\") and
dollar signs (\$)
"
ACTUAL_PAGER="${PAGER:-"less -R"}"
echo "$TEXT" | $ACTUAL_PAGER

This works pretty well in bash, but in zsh I get zsh: command not found: less -R, which I assume is zsh not able to handle the expansion of ACTUAL_PAGER. Also if PAGER is set to more I get the control characters around "Hello World".
Is there a way to get this to behave well in bash, zsh, and beyond?

Instead of relying on word-splitting of the unquoted variable expansion $ACTUAL_PAGER perhaps you could pass the -R option via the LESS environment variable?

Just write it out explicitly:
if [ -z "$PAGER" ]; then 
  ACTUAL_PAGER="less -R"
else
  ACTUAL_PAGER="$PAGER"  
fi

But why would you try to write a script for multiple languages? If you want a portable script, write in plain POSIX shell, if not, specify the shebang you want so the script runs with the correct interpreter. You wouldn't try to write a single script that runs in Python and Perl, why are you trying to write a single script that runs in bash and zsh?
